# Error in Http package and JsonPlaceholder while running

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting this error many times in ***Flutter*** when I want to use the JsonPlaceholder API, and I downloaded a package named HTTP package in pub.dev/flutter , used in pubspec.yaml , but I can't get the data it gives the same error every time I run the application,

```
 ([ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'jsonplaceholder.typicode.com' (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7)) ,
```

Here is the code I used inside my  stateful Widget class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
class Loading extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoadingState createState() => _LoadingState();
}
class _LoadingState extends State<Loading> {
  void getData() async{
  Response response =  await get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
  print(response.body);
  }
  @override
  initState()  {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Loading Screen'),
           ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in various stages.

- Did not import the **package** right
- Did not perform the **operation right in the method**

We will sort this out one by one. Refer to the [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) documentation, by selecting the link give. Now let us jump into the code

**1. Importing the package right**

```
// refer documentation as well
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

**2. Using the method right**

```
  void getData() async{
    // see the difference, it is http.get()
    Response response =  await http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
    print('Response body: ${response.body}');
  }
```

Now that you call your method in your `initState()`, you will get the data in your console.

Also, it is a good practice to take a look at the `response code`, if it is `200`, it is `OK`, else return an error message.

```
  void getData() async{
    // see the difference, it is http.get()
    Response response =  await http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
    
    if(response.statusCode == 200) print('Response body: ${response.body}');
    else print('Some error happened, here is the status code: ${response.statusCode}')
  }
```